# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException

Tags: php, mysqli

I have problem ... and I know that it easy to solve by anyone ... but i can not solve it ... 
Im trying to connect to server in my android application ... 
I send request to server ... server return to me a JSON response ...
all it worck succefuly .. but i have a small wrong ... that with response it return an ignored character ... 
my request url is for php file suppose its named : 'file.php'
file.php is as bellow :

**file.php**

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mypackage/connection/connection.php';

$response = array();
$var = new connection();
$conn = $var->GetConnection();

$result = null;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *FROM table1");

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $products = array();
        $products["id_products"] = $row["id_products"];

        array_push($response["products"], $products);
    }

    $response["success"] = 1;

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I write my connection to my database in php class located in folder named 'connection'

my connection.php is as bellow:

**connection.php**

```
<?php 
class connection {
    private $conn;

    public function GetConnection() {
        $conn = mysqli_connect("domain_name", "database_username", "database_password", "database_table");
        return $conn;
    }

    public function CloseConnection($connection) {
        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
}
?>
```

As I tell you befor , all it worck ... the response from request is as bellow :

***ï»?{"products":[{"id_products":"1"}],"success":1}***

with this erreur:

```
Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»? of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

this character ' **ï»?** ' Where it came from ???? !!!!!!!! 
this is my problem : this character 'ï»?' Where it came from ???? !!!!!!!!

Best regards and thanks in advance, Fadel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
    data: JSON.stringify(your response data);
```

For more information about JSON.stringify check this [stringify in json](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)